# How to increase Log Limit of Docker? | [output clipped, log limit 100KiB/s reached]

Tags: python, docker, github, azure-devops, python-poetry

My goal is to execute **Docker**, from **GitHub**, on an **Azure DevOps** pipeline.

**Why does my code exit?**

---

Theories:

I *thought* it exits because it fails to download `torch-xla==1.8`.

I now suspect this fails due to a **log limit**?:

```sh
#17 9.115 [output clipped, log limit 100KiB/s reached]
```

**How do you increase a log limit?**

Is this concerning **Docker or Azure DevOps**?

---

```sh
#17 [test 5/5] RUN cd ontology_tagger && poetry run invoke deploy
#17 sha256:3581942486c3acb9ab1c41574317a3ec25db6fbbb8fb47af887c47e5a6e1e607
#17 3.046 ============================= test session starts ==============================
#17 3.046 platform linux -- Python 3.7.12, pytest-3.10.1, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
#17 3.046 rootdir: /home/worker/python/ontology_tagger, inifile: pytest.ini
#17 3.046 collecting ... importing Jupyter notebook from /home/worker/python/ontology_tagger/ontology_tagger/notebooks/ontology_tagger.ipynb
#17 5.762 Collecting torch-xla==1.8

#17 6.315   Downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/tpu-pytorch/wheels/torch_xla-1.8-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl (144.6 MB)

#17 6.315 25l
     |                                | 10 kB 20.5 MB/s eta 0:00:08
...
     |███████████████████████▊        | 107.3 MB 41.9 MB/s eta 0:00:01
     |███���█
#17 9.115 [output clipped, log limit 100KiB/s reached]
#17 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cd ontology_tagger && poetry run invoke deploy]: exit code: 2
------
 > [test 5/5] RUN cd ontology_tagger && poetry run invoke deploy:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cd ontology_tagger && poetry run invoke deploy]: exit code: 2
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Test worker
```

Please let me know if there's anything else I should add to post.

Answer (score 0):

Docker uses the json-file log driver to save the log files by default and it doesn't limit the size of files. Below CLI command helps increasing the limits of the log driver container

```
docker run --log-opt max-size=10m --log-opt max-file=5 my-app:latest
```

Also if you are using system based Linux-distro server you need to add the following lines as below

`/etc/sysconfig/docker`:
BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SIZE=10000000
BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SPEED=10000000

For further information check [Docker build](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/484#issuecomment-767434491)

Also check [Rotating Docker Logs](https://medium.com/@Quigley_Ja/rotating-docker-logs-keeping-your-overlay-folder-small-40cfa2155412)